# Reporting attempt at cheating

Tags: ethics, cheating

To help finance my studies, I have been offering tutoring services for other students throughout the past year. Business has been good and students have been grateful for the help I have given them.

Today, a student I tutored one year ago e-mailed me and asked me to write an online exam for them, saying that they would compensate me financially for this "service". I was quite frankly offended that they could think, that I would go along with such a scheme.

Obviously I will reject the offer, but how should I go about doing this and what additional steps should I take? Should I simply not respond, or should I follow my inclination to chastise the student for even making the suggestion? While they have yet to actually cheat, I am strongly considering contacting their professor to alert them to the situation; if I reject the offer, the student is likely to contact someone else with lower moral standards.

Below is the full e-mail I received with identifying information redacted:

*"I don't know if you remember me, but you help me with [Course 1] during summer 2019. I am taking a [Course 2] deferral exam [on date] and due to the situation right now and the fact that I moved back home temporarily, I am not going to have enough time to study. The exam will be fully online and based on multiple-choice and short-answer questions. That said, I was wondering if you would ever consider taking the exam for me, I would never ask this if the exam will be in person, I am lacking time and I know is feasible because it is only.  You will only need to login into my [student portal] and perform the exam. I will compensate you of course and I am open to the price.  I left a copy of the textbook online and the final exam 2019 ( The professor said that it will be very similar). Please let me know if you decide to proceed with this or not."*

Edit 1:
Believe it or not, I have just received yet another request from a different student independently of the first one.

Edit 2:
I gathered the evidence I had and reported both students to the university administration.

Comment: wasn't a similar question asked a while back?

Comment: Perhaps the second requester is just a friend of the first. Don't read too much into that.

Comment: >> I have just received another request ...   Any chance someone is testing you?

Comment: Reply and say that would be fine if the relevant professor agrees, please send their contact info so you can follow up.

Comment: A minor point - your name is sufficiently unique that I quickly identified the university you are studying at, what you are doing there, and I could probably quickly start identifying friends of yours on FB that are from the same university etc. It is too late to change, but I believe posts like this are best done anonymously.

Comment: You didn't state, but are you a employee/student at the university in question? It's one thing to simply refuse to do this, another to report the student.

Comment: @Forgottenscience "It is too late to change.." no it's not. It's better than doing nothing.

Comment: @America, sure, but I don't think its that easy to delete an upvoted question with an accepted answer?

Comment: @Forgottenscience I wasn't referring to the deletion of the post, I was referring to Ole to change his name to an anonymous name

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your institution has an honor code or similar description of the requirements for academic conduct, it may prescribe what you must do.  The solicitation of a "ringer" to take the exam may itself be an offense.  If there's a prescribed action, follow it.

If not, consider that an accusation of cheating by the professor necessarily creates an adversarial situation.  If you do report this to the professor, please copy the department head, dean, chairman of the honor council.  Copy at least one other person who can support the professor.  Include a copy of the student's email with your report, and retain your own copy for a very long time.

Do not respond to the student.  Chastisement will not do any good, and while the student is awaiting your reply, he or she isn't looking for someone else to take the exam.

Comment: This is the correct thing to do: follow the institution's code of conduct.

Comment: The honor code may very likely have a clause stating that failure to report knowledge of a violation is itself a violation.

Comment: @pjs Correct.  The West Point Honor Code should be a model for all others: "A cadet will not lie, cheat, steal, or tolerate those who do."  It is the *or tolerate* part that requires reporting.  Soliciting help to cheat would likely be an offense at West Point because "attempting" to lie, cheat, or steal is an offense.  However, other institutions do things differently, which is why OP needs to read his own institutions regulations.

Comment: Sure, but expect the student tries to deny it by saying someone else accessed their email account, or that it was a prank. Seems to me the dept would require more verifiable proof than two emails from an unverified sender. So that might involve setting up a follow-up phone call.

Comment: @smci  Well, a student who cheats will lie.  That's why I wrote, "necessarily creates an adversarial situation."  The Honor Council, Dean, Department Head, or someone will eventually have to make a decision.  Setting up a phone call seems very dangerous to me.  I wouldn't advise doing it unless asked by Dean, etc.

Comment: @BobBrown: two emails from unverifiable source is zero verifiable evidence for disciplining someone, person wouldn't even need to hire a lawyer to get it overturned. I said I expect the university would follow up to request actual verifiable proof that the student themselves made the request. Identity of email senders is not verifiable. That's all. It's up to the university how/if they proceed, at all.

Comment: @smci  As a former chair of an honor council, I assure you that there's at least one institution that would take the allegation seriously.  Further, at least in the United States, many institutions consider email from a university account to have been electronically signed.  (OP didn't tell us whether university email was involved.)  As comments are not meant for discussion, I won't have anything further to say on this matter.

Comment: @BobBrown: obviously they wouldn't send it from their university email, if they had a clue they'd use another account. So take it it's unverifiable. Then all the university has is an unverifiable allegation. Not enough to suspend someone for.

Comment: @smci The burden of proof will likely be on the person who owns the mail. If it had been hijacked, they will have to find a plausibility argument for that. Universities do not operate like courts. They can make decisions on weaker criteria than courts or decide not to pursue on stronger criteria than courts would let pass. Unis do not have the resources of a jurisdictive system, and some rare (fortunately, only few) students blatantly lie, building a whole card house of lies on top of each other, bringing the next one forward, when the last one is dismantled.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: you're not listening to me. So if you get an email from 'throwaway_account@gmail.com', you can't prove who 'owns' it. Assume anyone with half a brain wouldn't send it from their own university account. That's why I already said 'unverifiable source'.

Comment: @smci I am quite surprised at the tone you take with me. You have no idea how much experience I have in matters. Perhaps I have none. Perhaps I have more than you. Who knows?  There is no indication that this student is anonymous to the tutor. You said yourself "expect the student tries to deny it by saying someone else accessed their email account" - this already indicates it would be possible to know whose email account it is. The story that "others accessed it" does not have to be believed by an academic committee. It's not a court, they can choose to disbelieve that statement.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: commonsense would suggest that anyone trying to cheat would likely do it from an unverifiable email or phone account. If someone emails you from an unverifiable account and says "Hi this is Bob", it doesn't prove it's Bob; it's moot whether that's "anonymous". And it's easy to impersonate another student, or access their email or phone unauthorized. And *""expect the student tries to deny it by saying someone else accessed their email account"* never said *"their official universty email account"*. So, we come back to whether the identity is verifiable.

Comment: @smci If you read the précis of OP's question, you will see that the student asks the OP to take the exam for the student. This means, not only is the student identifiable, but it seems they will also have to provide the student's online credentials (considered a proof of identity). I can imagine a contrived situation where someone wants to harm the student by knowing their precise failure pattern (deferral/referral), stealing their credentials (and possibly paying the tutor to be examined in their lieu). But any board will assume the rather more obvious case that this student tried to cheat.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: I had read it, multiple times. It appears to say *"A person claiming to be (or with access to the email of) a student [OP] tutored one year ago e-mailed them"*. Didn't say from which account. And no it doesn't say anywhere they have yet provided the student's online credentials, it only says *"You will only need to login into my [student portal]"*; obviously (if this was really them) they *would* have to, if this is really them and if they proceeded with this plan. Hence as I said above, further email/phone contact is likely needed to verify it actually was that student.

Answer (score 19):

I won't argue against reporting the student as [Bob Brown](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/147439/75368) suggests. But also suggest that if you advertise your services in any way that you make it clear in your advertising that you won't aid students in any dishonest work and, if you feel strongly enough about it, that you will report requests. Even if you don't advertise you could tell each client that you will only perform ethical services.

That would head off future requests, I think.

But if you aren't willing to report this student at this time, I'd suggest that you let them know that you don't do such things and that you will report future requests.

The devil on my right shoulder is, of course, whispering in my ear suggesting that you fail the exam for the student, though the angel on my left is trying to suggest more sensible alternatives. Listen to the angel.

Comment: > _"The devil on my right shoulder "_ Do not even start listening to him. By doing so you will leave a trail of you _agreeing to unhonest action_, receiving login credential and possibly getting paid. This will open you to blackmail and possible career problems.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Agreed. The fact that the student cheats should not turn OP into a cheater. I recommend removing this part of the response, it might tempt some readers. I do agree with the idea of preempting such questions in the future by announcing that on your service site, including the reporting. Then, nobody will be able to complain when OP does that.

Comment: In your advertisement of services you might also want to put a link to the institution's honor code, including --- if it exists --- a link to the part that requires you to report instances of attempted cheating.

Comment: `suggesting that you fail the exam for the student`  This is even more abhhorent than the original request.  Why would you even suggest such a thing in a respected forum like this?  It's so grossly irresponsible that it's not even funny as a joke.

Comment: I specifically point it out @J..., because others will think of it and I want to recommend against it. Devil... Get it? Jokes sometimes have a serious intent. I would expect people here to be sophisticated enough to grok that. But maybe I'm wrong and need to be bloody literal minded in all things. And you are clearly quoting out of context.  Naughty Naughty

Comment: @Buffy you may wish to add, then, the lawyer standing between the two who points out that even a "neutral" examination of the issue points to that being not just ethically unsound, but a terribly dangerous idea personally for a number of objective/pragmatic reasons, primarily the chances of getting caught at it (multiple ways this can happen) and thereby found guilty of academic misconduct on OP's part, and possibly even criminal fraud among other possibilities if it went beyond the University looking into it, even ignoring the possibility of retaliation via extortion/etc.

Comment: @Buffy On the internet, jokes are dangerous. For a joke, you need to know your audience. I often delete the by far funniest/best part of my responses before posting them, for precisely that reason. And every time my devil tempts me to include them, the little lawyer raises its finger and says: "no". Anyway, I hope whoever reads your response and is tempted will also read the comment section.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs A longstanding problem with a longstanding solution: "I propose that [sic] the following character sequence for joke markers:   :-)" [(Fahlman 1982)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sef/Orig-Smiley.htm)

Comment: @Ray Voted your comment up. Nonetheless, it may still not be enough for misunderstandings which can be unintentional or intentional or sometimes even of unclear intentionality to the person who misunderstands until after the $%!# has hit the fan... :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is typically an office which is in charge of enforcing academic integrity. For example, the Office of the Provost and Vice-president for Academic Affairs. Simply forward the email to them. There is nothing gained by responding to the student.

Comment: In response to (now-deleted) comments: As impressed as I am by the effort, I'm not convinced trying to track and broadcast personal information (even if using only publicly-available sources) is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Ole, keep in mind that we all make mistakes at some point in our lives, the younger the more silly things one could end up doing..

I'd simply reply to the student saying that,

> that's dishonest, unethical and that's counterproductive to him/her, if not now, maybe later.. independently of the situation we're passing through. And that you sincerely hope to think twice about it. And given that this is the first time saying such things, you won't report them. If they insist, report them to the professor.

In some places, the punishment for cheating or attempting to cheat are *very* severe. I don't know in which case they are, keep that in mind also.

Also, if reporting them, most likely their name wouldn't be the 'same' again, because professors tend to share their *experiences* with students, with other professors.

Answer (score 1):

Just refuse, and offer them help to practice/tutor. This leaves the bridge intact (instead of burned, blown up and then burned again) for a future cooperation while keeping you moral and professional. Probably gets the word of mouth around, and no other students will reach you with the same request.